# C# my Event is always Null... why...?

Tags: c#, wpf

/* class library */
/* calcEventArgs.cs */

```
   namespace calc1
   {
       public class calcEventArgs
       {
       }

       public class CalculationCompletedEventArgs : System.EventArgs
       {        
           public string StringValue { get; set; }
           public int IntegerValue { get; set; }
       }
   }
```

/* CalcMain.xaml.cs */

```
  namespace calc1
   {
       public partial class CalcMain : Page
       {
           public delegate void CalcEventHandler(object sender, CalculationCompletedEventArgs e);
           public event CalcEventHandler CalculateCompletedEvent;

           public CalcMain()
           {
               InitializeComponent();
           }  

           private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
           {
               CalculationCompletedEventArgs pArgs = new CalculationCompletedEventArgs();
               pArgs.StringValue = "1 + 1";
               pArgs.IntegerValue = 2;

               CalcEventHandler eh = CalculateCompletedEvent;
               if (eh != null) eh(this, pArgs);
           }
       }
   }
```

/* EventTest application program */

```
namespace EventTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            calc1.CalcMain c = new calc1.CalcMain();
            c.CalculateCompletedEvent += new calc1.CalcMain.CalcEventHandler(CalcfromPage);
        }

        private void CalcfromPage(object sender, calc1.CalculationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.StringValue + " = " + e.IntegerValue.ToString());
        }
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            fraMainScreen.Navigate(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/calc1;component/CalcMain.xaml", UriKind.Absolute));
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code
i have problem ...
CalcEventHandler eh = CalculateCompletedEvent

CalculateCompletedEvent is always null..

help..
thanks. ^^

Comment: `calc1.CalcMain c = new calc1.CalcMain()`, do you ever add this control to the window?

Comment: Try deleting that line, CalcEventHandler eh = CalculateCompletedEvent;

Comment: @Philippe
this test code use  WPF, C#.
there  is Application Program (EventTest) and one Class library (calc1).

Comment: @Marco
delete??
if delete that line, how to occurred event?

Comment: my bad english... sorry..
and thanks.

Comment: Put a break point on the two following lines: (1) `CalcEventHandler eh = CalculateCompletedEvent;` & (2) `c.CalculateCompletedEvent += new calc1.CalcMain.CalcEventHandler(CalcfromPage);`. Does (1) occur before (2)?

Comment: You are attaching the event  handler to a `CalcMain` instance that is created in the MainWindow constructor by `calc1.CalcMain c = new calc1.CalcMain();` and then not used any more. It is *not* the page instance that you navigate to in `fraMainScreen.Navigate(new Uri("..."));` because navigation creates a new page instance. In other words, you are attaching the handler to the wrong page object.

Comment: Besides that, I guess it is generally a bad idea to attach an event handler to a Page from the MainWindow. During navigation, multiple instances of the Page may be created and you would have to take care (with a lot of programming overhead) to properly detach your handler from the pages when you navigate away from them.

Comment: @Clemens
I solved using a static event and class .^^
thanks.